# build prod failed: Unexpected value 'TagsInputModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic2-tags-input npm package to my ionic2 app. I am getting an error when do ionic run android with production mode (--prod). Could anyone suggest me where i am going wrong?

> build prod failed: Unexpected value 'TagsInputModule' imported by the
>   module 'AppModule'  [18:48:39]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
>   [18:48:39]  Error: Unexpected value 'TagsInputModule' imported by the
>   module 'AppModule'  Error: Unexpected value 'TagsInputModule' imported
>   by the module 'AppModule'

This my app.module.ts:

```
import { TagsInputModule } from 'ionic2-tags-input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      backButtonText: ''
    }), CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings), FormsModule, TagsInputModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp]
)}

export class AppModule { }
```

This is the template:

```
<tags-input formControlName="tags" (onTagAdded)="addTags()" [alertInputPlaceholder]="options.placeholder" [maxTags]="options.maxItems" [(ngModel)]="tags"></tags-input>
```

Comment: post the code that is failing. Cannot say anything based on your error.

Comment: This is my template:                                                                                  <tags-input formControlName="tags" (onTagAdded)="addTags()" [alertInputPlaceholder]="options.placeholder" [maxTags]="options.maxItems" [(ngModel)]="tags"></tags-input>

Comment: Just edit the original post and add it :)

Comment: Do you have code for AppModule.ts or something like that?

Comment: Yes i have. Edited

Comment: Could it be that extra bracket `}` before `export`?

Comment: No. Actually, i am gettting an error when ngc get started

Comment: It works fine in dev mode.Its throwing an error, only in prod mode